# iOS - SQLCipher subquery predicate not working in EncryptedStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, sqlcipher

I am having an existing coredata ios project which has lot of subquery predicate. I want to encrypt my sqlLite file. While implementing sqlchipher via EncryptedStore I am facing  "Unsupported expression type 4 ." for subquery predicate from the  the below method

```
- (void)parseExpression:(NSExpression *)expression
        inPredicate:(NSComparisonPredicate *)predicate
     inFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request
           operator:(NSDictionary *)operator
            operand:(id *)operand
           bindings:(id *)bindings {....}
```

Please suggest how to resolve this issue or any alternative solution

Comment: Take a look at this issue on GitHub, which indicates that subquery predicates are not supported: https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data/issues/52